# Stream and Play .m4a stream (Itunes preview Url) in android

Tags: android, stream, media-player, itunes, aac

I want to stream and play itunes preview urls like http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/044/Music/e9/40/ec/mzm.evyxvimp.aac.p.m4a. I tried to use [AAC Decoder Android](http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/) Library. By which  **I can** stream and play AAC stream urls like http://http.yourmuze.com:8000/play/paradise/l.aac. But it dnt stream m4a urls(Logcat says `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/044/Music/e9/40/ec/mzm.evyxvimp.aac.p.m4a`).

**How I can stream the .m4a links?**

My Code:

```
public class AACPlayerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,PlayerCallback{

private Button btnPlay;
private ProgressBar progress;
private Handler uiHandler;

private MultiPlayer multiPlayer;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    progress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    uiHandler = new Handler();
}

public void playerException(Throwable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void playerMetadata(String arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void playerPCMFeedBuffer(boolean arg0, final int audioBufferSizeMs, final int audioBufferCapacityMs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             progress.setProgress( audioBufferSizeMs * progress.getMax() / audioBufferCapacityMs );
        }
    });
}

public void playerStarted() {

    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progress.setProgress( 0 );
            progress.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        }
    });

}

public void playerStopped(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progress.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
        }
    });

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(btnPlay.getText().equals("Play")){
        start();
        btnPlay.setText("stop");
    }else{
        stop();
    }
}


 private void start() {
        stop();
        // we cannot do it in playerStarted() - it is too late:
        multiPlayer = new MultiPlayer(this,MultiPlayer.DEFAULT_AUDIO_BUFFER_CAPACITY_MS, MultiPlayer.DEFAULT_DECODE_BUFFER_CAPACITY_MS);
        multiPlayer.playAsync("http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/044/Music/e9/40/ec/mzm.evyxvimp.aac.p.m4a");
    }


    private void stop() {
        if (multiPlayer != null) {
            multiPlayer.stop();
            multiPlayer = null;
        }
    }
```

**Updates**

1. I try to use [ServeStream](http://sourceforge.net/projects/servestream/) it says  the url could not be opened.
2. I try to use [Vitamio SDK](http://vov.io/vitamio/) it also fails to play the `itunes preview Urls`.

Is possible to play `itunes preview urls` in android?

Comment: What is `MultiPlayer`?  Have you tried just passing the URL to Android's default `MediaPlayer` instance?

Comment: I tried that but android default media player can't stream the aac stream urls. So i tried using AAC decoder library which uses the MultiPlayer instead of MediaPlayer. But it is also not Streaming.

Comment: I'm the developer of ServeStream. I tried the URL you provided and it played without a problem using the latest version (0.4.11), FYI. ServeStream will meet your requirements.

Comment: @WilliamSeemann I tried on this url http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/044/Music/e9/40/ec/mzm.evyxvimp.aac.p.m4a using the latest version (0.4.11), It shows the url could not be opened.

Comment: Just tried it in an emulator running API 15, worked perfectly. Perhaps your device doesn't support this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with media  formats etc. Apple simply prevents non-Apple clients to access previews. You can spoof User-Agent header and access to previews.

Read my relevant blog post here: http://ahmetalpbalkan.com/blog/how-to-bypass-itunes-music-previews-protection/ Thats why you get 404 while playing music on Android. this should answer your question.

Comment: i think also like that... is there any regional restrictions only? see William Seemann's comment... But using  ServeStream it never worked for me.. I tested it from different devices and simulator from india.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [ServeStream](http://sourceforge.net/projects/servestream/):

> HTTP media server browser and stream player for Android.
>
> **Features:**
>
> - Supports Android 2.2+, 3.0+ (No support for < 2.2)
> - Plays Android supported media files
> - Additional support for m3u, m3u8, pls and asx playlists
> - Supports multitasking/playing audio in the background
> - Repeat and shuffle modes
> - Alarm clock support
> - Home screen widget
> - Utilizes HTML parsing to allow navigation of HTTP media servers that serve HTML pages

Comment: thank you for your response, I tried the app. It also shows the url could not be opened...

Comment: I'm the developer of ServeStream. I tried the URL you provided and it played without a problem using the latest version (0.4.11), FYI. ServeStream will meet your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

M4A and AAC are supported by Android. I would recommend to read this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Just couple of thing which you should be aware of
a) Older devices may have no particular coded or format support (especially, if you go below OS 2.2)
b) Some cheap devices may have quite strange things integrated in audio/video stack. I saw it on couple of cheap Chinese devices.

So, you can try to use MediaPlayer API to play it:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

You can take a look at example here:
http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/03/api-gaps-android-mediaplayer-example.html

Comment: I tried this also. But not streaming. I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Did you grant permission to access internet? I think the problem is that it can't access it (vs. it can't play it)

Comment: Did you try it on emulator or on a device? I recommend to try it on some of latest devices from major manufacturer. As I wrote I saw a lot of different issues with media on older devices and also emulator had (may be stil have) problems with playing media files.

Comment: One other idea for your (long shot) is to compile Android source code (http://source.android.com/), add Logs into MediaPlayer method you are using to see why it returns FileNoFoundException.

Comment: i tried on nexus s and defy. thanks for new methode. I will look into it and inform you later what happens.